# Проблема с click <td>

Tags: javascript, html, smarty

Возникла проблема, при нажатии на таблицу не отрабатывает javascript

Сам код:

```
<script>
 var table = document.getElementById("tableID");
    if (table != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
            table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
                tableText(this);
            };
        }
    }

    function tableText(tableCell) {
        alert(tableCell.innerHTML);
    }
</script>
<h2>Напраления</h2>

<table class="table table-hover" "id="tableID" style="cursor: pointer;">
<tr>
    <th>Выбирете направление</th>
</tr>
{foreach from=$locations key=id item=val}
<tr id="admin-locations-list-{$val.id}">
<td>{$val.locationname}</td>

</tr>
{/foreach}
</table>              </div>  


        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Использую библиотеку Smarty значения получаю из базы в `<td>` и дальше (в будущем при помощи ajax будет открываться форма). Но что бы я сейчас не делал javascript не в какую не хочет отрабатывать. Прошу Вашей помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> if (table != null) {
> ```

Это условие ложно. Поменяй таблицу и скрипт местами.

Но вряд ли заработает. Правильнее повесить обработчик на саму таблицу и проверять target.

Comment: Всё спасибо за напутствие $("td").click(function(e) так заработало